# WHAT is transformBy in winningPlan in MongoDB explain results?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I just wanna optimize my query performance. My query is an aggregate query, first stage is $match to filter the data and actually, I care only optimize this stage. Take a look below code:

My doc structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("649bf9f44086910c8205ebe2"),
    "s" : ObjectId("64813b95b7dbf1001217b044"),
    "u" : "2345235235235",
    "a" : 1,
    "v" : 1,
    "value" : 0.0,
    "t" : ISODate("2023-06-28T09:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdBy" : ISODate("2023-06-28T09:14:28.325Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2023-06-28T09:14:28.325Z")
}
```

My query example:

```
db.collection.explain('allPlansExecution').aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
      a:3,
      v:6,
      s: ObjectId('6475723afe6c4d0013036f97'),
      t:{
        $lte: ISODate('2023-10-11T01:00:00.000Z'),
      },
      $or:[
        {
          u:'8278261678812',
          t:{
            $gte:ISODate('2022-11-01T01:10:27.397Z'),
            $lte:ISODate('2023-10-11T08:27:04.467Z'),
          },
        },
        {
          u:'7889189237333',
          t:{
            $gte:ISODate('2023-06-23T04:53:12.221Z'),
            $lte:ISODate('2023-10-14T06:12:54.067Z'),
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        t: '$t',
        s: '$s',
      },
      data: {
        $push: {
          u: '$u',
          v: '$value',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'collection_b',
      localField: '_id.s',
      foreignField: 'sId',
      let: {
        time: '$_id.t',
      },
      as: 'extendData',
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $or: [
              {
                a: 1,
                v: 6,
              },
              {
                a: 0,
                v: 1,
              },
            ],
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                '$t',
                '$$time',
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            value: 1,
            a: 1,
            v: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: '$_id.t',
      data: 1,
      potatoBayAlgoHourly: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1,
    },
  }
])
```

In result of explain query, I see: (Full Object Here: http://jsonblob.com/1161927149279371264 )

```
"winningPlan": {
  "stage": "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
  "transformBy": {
    "s": 1,
    "t": 1,
    "u": 1,
    "value": 1,
    "_id": 0
  },
}
```

With this query, I created 2 indexes: `{ s: 1, u: 1 }` and `{ s: 1, u: 1, a: 1, v: 1 }`

My question: How mongo chooses the index to apply? I expect it choose second index, but It choose first index. And WHAT is `transformBy` ? Seems the index chosen base on `transformBy`? WHY my query is transformed to that query?

Comment: What's your goal with this question, to try and figure out why a specific index is chosen or to learn what `transformBy` means? Also, you state that you "_care only optimize this stage_" but MongoDB is going to plan the query as a whole. In fact, the answer to the question about `tranaformBy` is directly related to that. Please pick a question and update your description to focus on it, adding the full aggregation and explain plan (`"allPlansExecution"` mode) to it. Finally, why do you have the first index? Looks like it is redundant based on the second one anyway

Comment: @user20042973 I updated my question for more detail. I cannot push full result of query because it's too long. Please see on the attached link, I just want to know how mongo choose index and it's based on transformBy or not, and how transformBy be generated

Answer (score 1):

To answer the direct question - `transformBy` describes projected fields in a projection stage. From https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/fc174d081bdd6a5178cc888e6f0309d23504b4df/src/mongo/db/query/plan_explainer_impl.cpp#L428:

```
} else if (isProjectionStageType(stats.stageType)) {
    ProjectionStats* spec = static_cast<ProjectionStats*>(stats.specific.get());
    bob->append("transformBy", spec->projObj);
```

Now the question implies it is related to an index used in the query - it is not.

Furthermore, there is no way for the aggregation pipeline in the question to result with such projection, as _id field should be explicitly removed from the result to became `_id:0` in the "transfomBy".

Worse, the aggregation itself makes very little sense. There is no point to have a single condition in the `$or` array of the `$match` stage. It doesn't provide an alternative, so

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
      a:3,
      v:6,
      s: ObjectId('6475723afe6c4d0013036f97'),
      t:{
        $lte: ISODate('2023-10-11T01:00:00.000Z'),
      },
      $or:[
        {
          u:'8278261678812',
          t:{
            $gte:ISODate('2022-11-01T01:10:27.397Z'),
            $lte:ISODate('2023-10-11T08:27:04.467Z'),
          },
        },
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

is identical to

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $match:{
      a:3,
      v:6,
      s: ObjectId('6475723afe6c4d0013036f97'),
      u:'8278261678812',
      t:{
        $gte:ISODate('2022-11-01T01:10:27.397Z'),
        $lte:ISODate('2023-10-11T01:00:00.000Z'),
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Update**

The updated question allows to answer the rest of the question, but first I have to highlight that according to the "explain" results the second index is `{ u: 1, s: 1, a: 1, viable: 1, t: 1 }` - the order of the fields, the number of the fields, and and names of the fields differs from the index in the OP.

So,

**How mongo chooses the index to apply?**

It's a complex process described in https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-plans/  Basically the planner runs all options on a small subset and picks the best.

**I expect it choose second index, but It choose first index.**

The second index was considered, but was rejected. Considering

```
    "executionStats": {
      "executionSuccess": true,
      "nReturned": 0,
```

there are no matching documents. I find that in such extremes, the shorter index have more chances to win, but there are other factors that may affect it - selectivity of the fields, availability in the working set, etc.

**And WHAT is transformBy**

addressed in the original answer

**Seems the index chosen base on transformBy**

No

**WHY my query is transformed to that query?**

It's implicit projecting for pipeline optimisation. The next blocking `$group` stage uses `t` and `s` for the key and `u` and `value` for the values, discarding everything else. It allows an implicit projection `{"t":1,"s":1,"u":1,"value":1,_id:0}` to pass only required fields to the grouping stage.

Comment: I agree with almost all of this answer and am impressed/appreciative of the link to the source code. My only nit is around the claim that the projection is not (at all) associated with index selection which isn't strictly true. All other things being equal, an index that fully covers a query (which is based on the projection) is often selected over an index that does not.

Comment: @user20042973 I agree, `transformedBy`  allows to revers-engineer the projection stage, which indeed can affects query planner. so yeah it is  kinda related but it's a very distant relative =)  and in this particular case, the query is not covered anyway.

Comment: @AlexBlex I updated my question for more details, I don't have any project stage in pipeline. For give me about my question not provide full query, result because it's too long and I need to change original info of the attribute's name. Please take a look

Comment: yeah, this is exactly why I prefer not to reverse-engineer / guess pre-conditions. It's implicit projecting for pipeline optimisation. The blocking $group stage uses `t` and `s` for the key and `u` and `value` for the values, discarding everything else. It triggers implicit projection `{"t":1,"s":1,"u":1,"value":1,_id:0}`

Comment: the result of explain query is not true totally, actually, the first index is existed index in DB,  and I see the $match conditions have some more attributes, so I created one more index for all used attributes in $match, but I still chosen first index, I think I need to create a new question for more details and exactly. @AlexBlex

Comment: `explain` rarely lies. It's generally accepted practice to assume the result of `explain` is totally true.  Now, the question turned to some kind of trial and error debugging session, so I propose to limit it scope to _I just want to know how mongo choose index and it's based on transformBy or not, and how transformBy be generated_  I believe I addressed all 3 questions. yes?